# Can we use multiple federation configurations in web.config for SSO?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, ws-federation

We have an asp.net webforms application that uses our own custom authentication. I have been tasked with allowing one of our customers to use single signon to our app and they have their own adfs server. The idea is that we would allow more customers to do this going forward.

The examples I see for allowing multiple federated parties to connect to our application involves us setting up our own ADFS server which management does not want to do.

I have not found any examples of setting up multiple federations through web.config. Can it be done?

Comment: So, when your customer accidentally misconfigures their server and sends through a claim that makes their users administrators for your whole product, will you still be sure that it makes sense to blindly trust other peoples identity providers, or will you want to insert a product in between that a) your application can *trust* and b) can perform appropriate claims transformation from other identity providers?

Comment: Is this purely for authentication purposes, or are you supposed to get roles/permissions/claims from this external provider?

Comment: The requirements given to me are that our app needs to validate authentication of the user by the authentication token provided, if they are not authenticated redirect them to their federated (identity provider). After they are authenticated use an e-mail claim given to us by their system to know who they are.

Comment: Damien, to answer your question I would prefer our own ADFS to handle validation but these are requirements given to me. With my research and limited understanding: we won't have to blindly trust authentication from another identity provider if they provide a certificate in the token that we can validate against. Maybe what I'm asking is impossible or unsafe in which case I would need to know and appreciate any information I can use to take back to my supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, he was able to do something similar:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2012/10/18/access-to-an-asp-net-website-via-multiple-authentications/

Personally, I still prefer setting up a federation product in front of the application. It doesn't have to be ADFS. You can use any federation product, either open source or commercial, as a proxy for you application.

Comment: I'd like to setup a federated product in front of the app but right now management has said no. Thank you for the response.